# Botão excluir não funciona!

Tags: php, session, post, phpmyadmin

Boa noite! Tenho uma página **excluirConta.php** que não está funcional, eis o código:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("../banco/conexao.php");

if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
    $query = "DELETE * FROM usuario WHERE id = " . $_SESSION['id'];
    $result = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);

    if (!$result) {
        die("Falha ao excluir dados.");
    } else {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.alert('Usuário Excluído com Sucesso!');</script>";
        echo '<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="1; URL="../index.php">';
        exit;

        header("Location: ../index.php");
    }
}
```

E aqui o form na qual estou passando a variável:

```
<form action="excluirConta.php?id=<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>" method="POST">

              <label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
                 <div class="col-md-8">
                     <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Excluir Conta"name="excluirUsuario" onclick="return confirm('Você está prestes a excluir a sua conta e todos os seus dados serão perdidos. Tem certeza?');" />
                 </div>
               </form>
```

Quando clico em excluir, a unica coisa que acontece é que a pagina atualiza e os dados aparecem na URL, como se estivesse pegando por GET, alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106060/discussion-on-question-by-alicia-botao-excluir-nao-funciona)

Comment: Eu estava esperando aparecer a opção de mover para o chat, mas ela não apareceu. Existe a possibilidade de eu mover a conversa para o chat a qualquer momento da conversa ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue o código da resposta:

```html
<div class="col-md-8">

  <a href="excluirConta.php?id=<?php echo $_SESSION['id'];?>" class="btn btn-danger">Excluir Conta</a>

</div>
```

Arquivo: **excluirConta.php**

```
<?php

session_start();
require_once("../banco/conexao.php");

if (isset($_GET['id'])) 
{
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $query = "DELETE FROM usuario WHERE id = $id";
    $result = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);

    if (!$result) {
        die("Falha ao excluir dados.");
    } else {

      $mensagem = 'Usuário Excluído com Sucesso';
      header("Location: ../index.php?msg=$mensagem");

    }
}?>
```

No arquivo **index.php**, insira o seguinte código:

```
<?php 

if(isset($_GET['msg']))
{
    echo "<script>alert('" . $_GET['msg'] . "');</script>";
}

?>
```